# UFT VB Script ( If Statement OR and AND )

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am QA Engineer and am new to UFT and vb script. I am comparing multiple conditions and UFT keeps erroring out when it reaches code on line 269 starting with the **(if statement)**. It's like it can't read the multiple conditions statement. My code works without the `AND` condition but I want it to work with the `AND` condition. My code is below. Any help is appreciated unfortunately organization still use vb scripting for automated tests.

```
Set PayDate_Calendar = Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayDate_Calendar") 
Set PayRoll_Calendar = Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayRoll_Calendar") 
Set Payroll_Out_Calendar = Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("Payroll_Out_Calendar")
Set PayPeriodStart_Calandar = Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayPeriodStart_Calandar")

    '------- PayDate_Calendar--------
If dayName = dayOne Or dayName = dayTwo Or dayName = dayThree Or dayName = dayFour  AND  PayDate_Calendar = "" Then
    Setting.WebPackage("ReplayType") = 2
    PayDate_Calendar.Click
    'Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayDate_Calendar").Click
    Call EnterDataInField(Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayDate_Calendar")," ")
    Call EnterDataInField(Browser("ADP_2").Page("ADP_10_Calendar").WebEdit("PayDate_Calendar"),(FormatDateTime(dayPlus,2)))
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AND are execute before OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6s7zy3d1(v=vs.84).aspx). Put () if needed.

```
If (dayName = dayOne Or dayName = dayTwo Or dayName = dayThree Or dayName = dayFour)  AND  PayDate_Calendar = "" Then
```

Comment: When I do that I get an error message in UFT saying Object dosen't support this property or method

Comment: By looking at your code, PayDate_Calendar is an object of type 'WebEdit'. You don't fetch value like that.

Use this...
(PayDate_Calendar).GetRoProperty("Value") = ""  


Also, not sure if the other variables used are of String type. e.g. dayName /dayOne ...

Comment: Okay will trying that now ill let you know.